# How i can to load own image to network in python?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have made a convolutional neural network to mnist data. Now I want to change the input to my image. How can I do it? need to save the picture in a specific format?In addition, how save all picture and train one after the other?I use in tensorflow with python.

Comment: that depends on your requirements... the neural network in tensorflow only knows tensors, not images, so you need to provide the information to the network by yourself... e.g. for audio data you would use fourier transofmration and such stuff to get the information the network needs

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow has support for bmp, gif, jpeg and png out of the box.

So load the data (read the file into memory as a 0D tensor of type string) then pass it to `tf.image.decode_image`  or one of the specialized functions if it doesn't work for some reason.

You should get back the image as a tensor of shape [width, height, channels] (channels might be missing if you only have a single channel image, like grayscale).

To make this work nice you should have all the images in the same format. If you can load all the images into ram and pass them in bulk go for it since it's probably the easiest thing to do. Next easiest thing would be to copy the images into tensorflow.Example and to `tf.TFRecordReader` to do the shuffling and batching. If all else fails I think you can setup the input functions to read the images on demand and pipe them through the batching mechanism but I'm not sure how I would do that.

Here's a [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image) to the tensorflow documentation related to images.

Comment: I have 10000  images in size 72×61. Now I want to take 60000 to train and 40000 to test, how I build a file that contain all images and the network take image one after second to learn? Like a file of mnist

Comment: @sagitrabilse That's about 400 MB. You should be able to load all those file in memory (iterate over the files, open, and read) and feed them in bulk to tensorflow (put them all in a list and pass the list in)